# Compiled AVR assembly binary does not seem to contain my instructions?

Tags: assembly, avr, atmel

So I've written and manually "assembled" the following piece of asm using the AVR instruction set PDF from their website.

```
ldi     r17, 0          ; 1110 0000 0001 0000
ldi     r18, 3          ; 1110 0000 0010 0011
ldi     r16, 0          ; 1110 0000 0000 0000
loop:  
    sbrc    r18, 0      ; 1111 1101 0010 0000
    add     r16, r17    ; 0000 1111 0000 0001
    lsl     r17         ; 0000 1100 0001 0001
    lsr     r18         ; 1001 0101 0010 0110
    brne    loop        ; 1111 01-- ---- ----
again:
    rjmp again          ; 1001 010- ---- 110- 
                        ; ---- ---- ---- ----
```

However when I actually assemble the file with Avra and dump the resulting `.hex` file in binary I get this:

```
0011101000110000
0011001000110000
0011000000110000
0011000000110000
0011001000110000
0011000000110000
0011000001000110
0100001100001101
0000101000111010
0011000100110000
0011000000110000
0011000000110000
0011000000110000
0011000100110000
0100010100110000
0011001000110011
0100010100110000
0011000000110000
0100010100110000
0011001000110000
0100011001000100
0011000000110001
0011000001000110
0011000100110001
0011000001000110
0011001000110110
0011100100110101
0100010000111001
0100011000110111
0011010000110101
0000110100001010
0011101000110000
0011001000110000
0011000000110001
0011000000110000
0011000001000110
0100011001000011
0100011000110010
0011000000001101
0000101000111010
0011000000110000
0011000000110000
0011000000110000
0011000000110001
0100011001000110
0000110100001010
0000110100001010
```

When I flash the hex file to an Arduino it runs fine (the given asm doesn't give any output, but I've made asm to turn off the led and such, which worked fine so I'm assuming this does as well).
Can somebody tell me what is going on here? Why are there so many extra bits and why can't I find any of my instructions?

Comment: The hex file is ascii, did you hex dump that? Yeah looks like that, you have for example `00001101` `00001010` `CR LF`. Instead of dumping just look at it in a text editor or simply display it in your terminal.

Comment: hi Jester, what do you mean by the .hex file is ASCII? Most of the bytes of the file don't translate to valid ASCII characters and visual studio code only wants to view the file as bytes in hexadecimal notation.

Comment: The file content is an ASCII text representation of the binary data, in hex.  Best plan: convert your machine code to hex like a normal person so you can easily search for it in the text `.hex` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you decided to take ASCII-text ".hex" file and convert it into strings of binary digits, unless you wanted to make our life harder.

I have converted those cryptic lines back to the `.hex` source:

```
:020000020000FC
:1000000010E023E000E020FD010F110F2695D9F745
:02001000FFCF20
:00000001FF
```

what is the ".hex" file - you can read, for example, [in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX).

First line :02 0000 *02* **0000** FC sets initial segment offset (0).

Second line :10 0000 *00* **10E023E000E020FD010F110F2695D9F7** 45 - it is where your code is contained. You can convert the highlighted string into a binary, if you want:

```
1110000000010000
1110000000100011
1110000000000000
1111110100100000
0000111100000001
0000111100010001
1001010100100110
1111011111011001
```

As you can see all your code is there and intact.

Comment: Ah I see now, my understanding of the make up the hex file was wrong entirely, thanks for you clear explanation!